# ssh connection timed out on windows 11 when connecting to specific WiFi router

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ssh, connection

I have a strange issue with the SSH connection on Windows 11

When I try to access my VPS via SSH, I have got the connection timed out error. But when I change the router everything is fine.

I do the following steps:

- Network Reset doesn't help.
- Disabling Firewall doesn't help.
- Hotspot mobile data (4G) **working fine**.
- Hotspot mobile data (when connecting to the same WiFi) doesn't work.
- Connect via Debian on WSL - It **works fine**.
- Connecting to SSH via another PC on the same network **works fine**.

The PC connects via a WiFi USB dongle to the access point.
I think windows has an issue and should be reinstalled.
And maybe for the VPN tools that I have installed.

I need some way to trace where the problem is. for instance, I install WireShark but can't see any recode with "ssh" filter even when I connect via hotspot.

Note 1: I can open a website that is hosted on the same VPS therefore IP and port (80,443) are open and accessible.

Note 2: Sometimes the connection to WiFi is disconnected for no reason and connects after a minute.

Note 3: My PC's distance from the Wireless modem is about 8 meters.

Comment: What is connecting to a hotspot and wireless? Please expand how you are connecting and what the specific circumstances are when it fails.

Comment: Don't add comments with requested info please. The goal is for your question to get better. Use of the EDIT button is strongly encouraged.